# ASP NET - delete row using dataset in SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, dataset

having issues with deleting a datarow using dataset in a sql database

```
ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Delete()
```

Using above code gets me the error: `Expression does not produce a value.`

I'm using it like this:

```
tohtml += "<a role='button' onclick='" + ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Delete()
```

Comment: [Try this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137878/delete-all-row-from-datatable-in-dataset?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

May be your missing AcceptChanges.
// Delete row

```
dTable.Rows[1].Delete();

dTable.AcceptChanges();
```

Here you can check complete CRUD Operation:
http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/131/datatable-adding-modifying-deleting-filtering-sorting-rows-readingwrit