# Database does not change after clearing all rows

Tags: c#, database, datatable

I'm having major problems trying to clear a DataTable in C#.

At all other points when editing information in the database, I've used something like

```
somethingTableTableAdapter1.Update(greenParksDataSet);  
greenParksDataSet1.AcceptChanges();
```

and this has worked just fine. However, in one of my forms I have a button to clear the open table. It seems to clear the DataTable in memory, but not actually propagate the changes to the database. Essentially the code boils down to

```
greenParksDataSet.HistoryTable.RecieptIDColumn.AutoIncrementSeed = -1;
greenParksDataSet.HistoryTable.RecieptIDColumn.AutoIncrementSeed = -1;
greenParksDataSet.HistoryTable.RecieptIDColumn.AutoIncrementSeed = 1;
greenParksDataSet.HistoryTable.RecieptIDColumn.AutoIncrementSeed = 1;
greenParksDataSet.HistoryTable.Rows.Clear();


historyTableTableAdapter.Update(greenParksDataSet);
greenParksDataSet.AcceptChanges();
```

I've tried messing around with the order of things but nothing seems to work. With that code on its own, the DataTable is cleared (and the changes are shown in the DataGridView) but when adding a `historyTableTableAdapter.Fill(greenParksDataSet.HistoryTable);` after that, it is shown that the database is not being changed whatsoever.

I've probably missed something obvious, but I've been puzzling over this for ages, and any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delete all rows in a datatable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/955427/delete-all-rows-in-a-datatable)

Comment: `AcceptChanges` is called from `TableTableAdapter.Update` implicitely, hence it's rredundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955427/delete-all-rows-in-a-datatable).

Clear just works on the datatable in memory - it does not flag them for deletion.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. However, now I am getting the error: `Update requires a valid DeleteCommand when passed DataRow collection with deleted rows.`

Comment: @Cesque Does your set have a valid primary key (i.e. unique, non-null and indicated as such in the metadata)?  If you don't provide a delete command yourself, the adaptor can delete ONLY IF it knows it has a primary key to be able to identify the rows when it goes to delete them.

Comment: I do indeed have a primary key, but apparently the DataSet hadn't generated a DeleteCommand for the TableAdapter. Everything is fixed now and my table is being cleared! In case anyone has the same problem, just going through the TableAdapter Configuration Wizard for the TableAdapter fixes things.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using a binding source so try this :

```
greenParksDataSet.HistoryTable.Rows.Clear();
HistoryTableBindingSource.EndEdit();

historyTableTableAdapter.Update(greenParksDataSet);
greenParksDataSet.AcceptChanges();
```